# stmt->execute not working properly

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get a result from the below piece of code, however, no result is being returned.  `$stmt->execute(array(id))` is not running as expected.  It seems to work fine in other pieces of code, and I have compared them and don't see any differences.

```
$stmt = $mysql->dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM keys WHERE type = ?");
if($stmt->execute(array($id))) {
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo $row["price"];
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`keys` is a MySQL reserved word

- **http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html**

Either you wrap it in backticks or use another name for it.
Just don't rename it to `key`. That too is a MySQL reserved word.

```
SELECT * FROM `keys`
```

Using error exception would have thrown you an error.

Add `setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)` right after the connection is opened, if you're not already doing so.

Consult: **http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php**

- Assuming you have already established a successful DB connection.

Comment: Ah.  Thanks much for the help as well as the attribute.